# Pandas: Plotting / annotating from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There is this boring dataframe with stock data I have:

```
date         close    MA100      buy   sell
2022-02-14   324.95   320.12     0     0
2022-02-13   324.87   320.11     1     0
2022-02-12   327.20   321.50     0     0
2022-02-11   319.61   320.71     0     1
```

Then I am plotting the prices

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = ...
df['close'].plot()
df['MA100'].plot()

plt.show()
```

So far so good...
Then I'd like to show a marker on the chart if there was buy (green) or sell (red) on that day.
It's just to highlight if there was a transaction on that day. The exact intraday price at which the trade happened is not important.

So the x/y-coordinates could be the date and the close if there is a 1 in column buy (sell).

I am not sure how to implement this.
Would I need a loop to iterate over all rows where buy = 1 (sell = 1) and then somehow add these matches to the plot (probably with annotate?)

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the data frame for sell/buy and scatter plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x='date', y=['close', 'MA100'], ax=ax)
df.query("buy==1").plot.scatter(x='date', y='close', c='g', ax=ax)
df.query("sell==1").plot.scatter(x='date', y='close', c='r', ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]